# Google Assistant ends conversation

Tags: actions-on-google, chatbot, google-home

We're currently testing our chatbot project for Google Assistant/Google Home.

In the middle of the conversation, when our bot still has "things to say" (our chatbot flows are based on several steps and not just one question and one short answer), Google Assistant throws you out of the chatbot and goes back to the generic Google Assistant. Does anyone know if this is a feature of the testing version or if this is caused by the way Google Assistant works?

Comment: Can you provide more information like the responses given and possibly a code snippet?

Comment: Concur with @NickFelker. Also, if you are testing this with the Simulator, updating the question with the text the "Request", "Response", and "Debug" tabs for where you're kicked out may help as well.

Answer (score 0):

there is a 5 second timeout on Dialogflow fulfillment responses so if it takes your chatbot more than 5 seconds to respond, it will show the response that is defined in Dialogflow

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things that are most probably causing your app to exit in the middle of the conversation.

1. You webhook/fulfillment is encountering an error that is not handled.
2. The response that you are returning is exceeding the max limit of characters that Google supports.
3. A timeout is happening for your webhook because DialogFlow will wait for 10 seconds for your fulfillment to return a response or else it will end the conversation on its own.

Hope this helps.